# Debugger Win32 Local vs WinDbg in Ida vs Ollydbg

Tags: ida, ollydbg, static-analysis, windbg

When I do dynamic analyze of exe file I have few option , and I want to know what are the advantages and disadvantages.

I know that Ida designated for static analyze , but there are some debugger in Ida and lot of time I do dynamic analyze with those debuggers

1. When I choose Ida I can choose between Win32 debugger or WinDbg debugger, what is the difference ?
2. What is the difference between debug with Ida and debug with OllyDbg?

Answer (score 3):

1. Win32 debugger is IDA's internal debugger, whereas WinDbg is Microsoft's debugger. They both effectively do the same thing. IDA's debugger is probably better integrated with IDA.
2. I'm going to make a recommendation here to use [x64dbg](https://x64dbg.com/#start). Ollydbg is outdated and unsupported. IDA's debugger works but the interface is clunky and isn't as easy to use as x64dbg. Plus if IDA's debugger crashes, you risk corrupting your IDA database. If x64dbg crashes you don't lose anything except a few minutes of time.

Comment: can you please give me example/s what I can't do/ hard to do  with  IDA's debugger  and easy to do with x64dbg?